# ECS Tasks Stuck in Provisioning After Switching to t4g.medium Instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have an AWS ECS cluster that was initially using an autoscaling group with t2.medium instances. I recently created a new launch template that uses t4g.medium instances and set the default launch version to the t4g version. However, after making this change, I've noticed that my ECS tasks are getting stuck in the "provisioning" state and never reach the "running" status, even though the autoscaling group is successfully creating new t4g.medium EC2 instances.

Here is a summary of the changes I made:

Created a new launch template with t4g.medium instances.
Set the default launch version to the t4g version.
Confirmed that new t4g.medium instances are being created by the autoscaling group.
I am looking for assistance in understanding why my tasks are stuck in the "provisioning" state and not transitioning to the "running" state. Are there any specific configurations or changes that I need to make when switching from t2.medium to t4g.medium instances? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

In addition to the details provided above, it's worth mentioning that I am using an AMI which is being built using a Docker container from a code project and subsequently pushed to AWS ECR. My expectation is that this AMI should be portable and function correctly across different instance types, given that it works within a Docker container environment.

To elaborate:

I've set up a project where the Docker container builds an AMI.
This AMI is then pushed to AWS ECR.
I'm under the impression that, since the AMI is built in a Docker container, it should work seamlessly across various instance types, including both the t2.medium and t4g.medium.
Despite this, I'm experiencing the aforementioned issue where tasks get stuck in the "provisioning" state after transitioning from t2.medium to t4g.medium instances. I'm eager to understand if the problem lies in my assumption about the portability of the AMI or if there's something else I'm missing in this transition. Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Check to see if the instances are passing their health checks. If they fail their health checks they will re-try the health checks over and over and over, and (by default) after a half hour or more ECS gives up on the instances and fails the deployment.

The way health checks are performed, including timings, is configurable.

Comment: Whats the max/min on ASG? Is there some sort of deregistration delay occurring?

Comment: Check in the ECS cluster for the list of instances that are registered with the cluster. If something changed with the EC2 instances, such as the instance profile permissions, then they may be failing to register themselves with the ECS cluster after starting up. If the registration with the cluster is failing then ECS will just sort of "hang" in provisioning mode forever because it has no connection to the instances it needs to deploy your tasks to.

Comment: so you are going from intel to graviton/arm based instances deliberately? Does the AMI you are using supports graviton?

Comment: @GregoryLedray please check snapshot above, the health check is unknown for both tasks ( one on top on t2.medium, then other stuck on the t4g.medium ) I don't know why their health check is un-known.

Comment: Stuck in provisioning with no healthcheck ever running... seems like it doesn't have permissions to pull the image from ECR.

Comment: There are logs for tasks and (I think?) services in the console. Check both of them and report on the log entries in the list. Also if you could share your service definition, task definition, security group setup, and launch template (if not on Fargate) that would be helpful. In my experience possible problems include: security groups blocking the image pulls, the image is getting pulled but failing during startup, the image is starting up but not running the task, the task is running but health check is failing. The logs can narrow down the list of potential problems.